# What is the best practice to implement user session variables in Blazor Server applications?

Tags: c#, session

I'm teaching myself to program, I'm experimenting with a Blazor Server application using c# and asp.net core.

Take the hypothetical class `Workspace`:

```
public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Each `user` may be associated to one-to-many instances of `Workspace`; this will authorise them to select one of said `Workspace` instances and perform create, read, update, and delete operations on the child `Item` instances (i.e. `Workspace.Items`). Note, these operations may be performed on different pages.

What is the best way to store a reference to the current `Workspace`? e.g. should I store the current `Workspace` as a property in a `User` account? or maybe there is a better way of recording the session state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Blazor Server you can store state data in several places, is full documented at [ASP.NET Core Blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server). Summary:

- **Server-side storage** For permanent data persistence that spans multiple users and devices, the app can use server-side storage. Options include: Blob storage, Key-value storage, Relational database, Table storage
- **URL**: For transient data representing navigation state, model the data as a part of the URL.
- **Browser storage**: For transient data that the user is actively creating, a commonly used storage location is the browser's localStorage and sessionStorage collections.
- **In-memory state container service**: Nested and un-nested components can share access to data using a registered in-memory state container. A custom state container class can use an assignable Action to notify components in different parts of the app of state changes.